# ExportasFixedformat throws error 1004 one to five times during 900 runs

Tags: excel, vba

Excel VBA macro

Error code:

```
Worksheets("Rapport").Range("print").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=filename
```

throws error 1004, but only between 1 or 5 times during 6-7 hours run of 900+ loops.

I hit debug and then hit the play button and it runs without error, and exports the file as intended. I dont change anything.

I have tried to put an application.wait 2 seconds in just before the export. Has not helped.

Comment: Maybe try wrapping the export in an error handler and re-try (perhaps after a short wait) if it errors the first time(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work, my macro looped 901 times and was not stopped once by the previous error. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams for suggesting.

```
myerrorhandler:
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
On Error GoTo myerrorhandler
Worksheets("Rapport").Range("print").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=filnavn
```